# how to post the value from a rich text field to chatter through the process builder

Tags: chatter, process-builder, richtextarea

We have a custom object and want to post to chatter when a new record of this type is created. We do this via a Process Builder flow.

This works well for most fields.
However, we also have a rich text field (a comments field) that we also want to have posted along in the post.

It seems all formatting breaks and that the html is posted like plain text in the chatter post. I did read already somewhere that not all html is supported in a chatter post but even html that IS supported like <b> </b> also doesn't work.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From memory you can turn rich text editing for chatter posts on and off. Are you sure that you have have it enabled in chatter?

Comment: yes it's enabled

Answer (score 0):

Right now, Process Builder and Flows do not support any rich text posts to Chatter. You can upvote this idea to try and change this: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lHqaQAE

Answer (score 0):

This article explains how it can be done pretty easily.
https://unofficialsf.com/post-rich-chatter-invocable-action/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).